# Forwarding different page in jsp

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I have a index.jsp in my project and I want to forward the different page depends on the condition. The following is my code :

```
  $.ajax({url: "some_url",
        type: "HEAD",
        timeout:1000,
        statusCode: {
            200: function (response) {
                callOnlinePage();
            },
            400: function (response) {
                callOfflinePage();
            },
            0: function (response) {
                callOfflinePage();
            }              
        }
    });

    function callOnlinePage(){
        <jsp:forward page="online.jsp"/>
    }

    function callOfflinePage(){
        <jsp:forward page="offline.jsp"/>
    }
```

javascript code is correct if I alert without putting jsp:forward tag. If I put them, it always go to online.jsp. If I put callOfflinePage function first, it forward to offline.jsp everytimes.

So, is there anyway I can do without changing the url. Please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand the difference between server side rendering and client side script code.

The problem here is that while the server is rendering the page it encounters the forward and forwards the page to respective url , in this case online.jsp being the first.

you will have to redirect the page from client side as the js code will be executed on client. you can use window.location property to navigate to certail url

```
function callOnlinePage(){
       window.location = "online.jsp";
    }
```